# "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." Error when using TextBox and HScrollBar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to create a form where you can enter the value using either a horizontal scroll bar, or a text box and the value (A number between 0-90) will show up on both of the methods in run time. I have got this to almost work however when you enter a value into the text box, and then remove the value, the error "Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid." appears and I'm not sure how to fix this. Thanks for any help

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub AngleScroll_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles AngleScroll.Scroll
    TextBox1.Text = AngleScroll.Value

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") _
        AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    AngleScroll.Value = TextBox1.Text

End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: It is simple to trigger the bug by using the Backspace key.  You need If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then ...

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` to avoid implicit conversions.  `AngleScroll.Value = TextBox1.Text`  Value is an integer but Text is string

Comment: BTW a `NumericUpDown` would probably be more appropriate by limiting user input to a numeric.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

**I would change this:**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    AngleScroll.Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

**To this:**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then AngleScroll.Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

The problem lies in the fact that your code is not handling the case where the textbox is empty.

When you remove all the numbers from the textbox, it's value becomes an empty string. An empty string is not an integer, and will not cast to an integer.

By ensuring the value in the textbox is numeric, no cast conversion is attempted when the textbox is empty, thereby eliminating the risk of an error.